# Is it possible to create an unsafe array buffer in the browser?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, buffer

In `node.js`, the `Buffer` implements a `Uint8Array`, which is also available in the browser.

There is a method in `node.js` to [create an unsafe buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_allocunsafe_size), where the bytes are not pre-initialized to 0. This is much faster to allocate since you don't have to zero out all the entries, and as long as you later fill everything, it is safe.

Is there anything like this in the client-side browser Javascript? For speed reasons when creating a large amount of arrays which I immediately fill with values, I'm looking for a way to unsafely allocate these buffers.

Comment: I do not think it's possible currently for browsers. All [Typed Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray#TypedArray_objects) have their contents initialized to zero, along with that the [Array Buffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) will  initialized its contents to zero. But if you are filling these values right away, why not just give the data to the constructor?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: Unfortunate, and by right away I mean in the next function call. Also, `var x = new Uint8Array(3); x[0] = 1; x[1] = 2; x[2] = 3;` is faster than `var x = new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3]);` (just profiled)

Comment: The client really should never allow JS to see uninitialized memory for security reasons because you don't want one piece of JS to be able to see what might have been left behind by another piece of code (potentially in another page from another site or even from some other process).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  [According to the specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/), all typed arrays are initialized to `0`s.